# JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a web api .I  got  the following error . same code structure working for fetchbyid ,post,edit . What did i wrong here . please help me.
Catalog.cs:

```html
  public class Catalog
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("VendorName")]
        public string VendorName { get; set; }

       // public List<Industy> Industy { get; set; }
        public Industy Industy { get; set; }

        public Catalog()
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
            else
            {
                Id = Id;
            }

         //   this.Industy = new List<Industy>();
        }
    }
```

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Catalog>> FetchListAsync(
           Guid? itemId)
        {
            var feedOptions =
                  new FeedOptions
                  {
                      MaxItemCount = -1,
                      EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                  };
            var query = new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c"

            };

            var orderDocumentQuery =
                _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Catalog>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                        _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query, feedOptions)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();

            var orderList =
                new List<Catalog>();
            Console.WriteLine(orderDocumentQuery.ToString());

            while (orderDocumentQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
                orderList.AddRange(
                    await orderDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Catalog>());
            }

            return orderList;
        }
```

error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CatalogAPI.Entities.Industy]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Industy.Id', line 1, position 117.

What do i doing wrong??

Comment: Could you please add the full `Catalog` class as well? Thanks.

Comment: added please check and help me sir

Comment: The exception error says that you have to use `public List<Industy> Industy`, not `public Industy Industy`. It's not possible to serialize an array into object.

Comment: Probably some items in your table have `Industry` property stored as objects(e.g. `indestry: { a: 1, b: 'test '}`) but there are also items with array `Industry` type(e.g. `industry: [{a: 1, b: 'test'}]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POCO object in Cosmos DB needs to have it's `id` field to be a string.

You need to replace `public Guid? Id { get; set; }` with `public string Id { get; set; }`.

Comment: yes it is working. and i change the return as return new List<Catalog>{catlog}; .thank you sir